# How to mass annotate constructor arguments?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, structural-search

I've got a problem where I want to make a lot of classes in our project de-serializable via jackson. The problem is that most of classes look like this:

```
public class FinalFieds{

    private final String field;
    private final String secondField;

    public FinalFieds(String field, String secondField)
    {
        this.field = field;
        this.secondField = secondField;
    }

    public String getField()
    {
        return field;
    }

    public String getSecondField()
    {
        return secondField;
    }
}
```

So what I found is that in jackson you can do something like this:

```
public FinalFieds(@JsonProperty("field") String field, @JsonProperty("secondField") String secondField)
```

And that works nice. The problem is that I cannot make structural replace in intellij to work for me. When I try:
[image]

All my matches are in "Unclassified matches" section.
Furthermore when I try to replace, Intellij just removes a constructor from the class.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or is it a known bug in intellij?

Even an overcomplicated regex that will help me replace this (for single argument constructors I can create it myself; the problem is that our constructors in those classes have multi-argument constructors).

Comment: you can always write a little program yourself, parsing (loosely) all your java files, find constructors and rewrite them.

Comment: Of course I could write a program, but it will take time and I would rather use my overcomplicated IDE, because what is the point of having complicated IDE when you cannot do what you want with your code. I was hoping structural search and replace would help me here... :(

Comment: maybe one day our overcomplicated IDE can write all codes for us.

Comment: No thanks :P But it would be nice to do some heavy lifting for us. I'm thankful for all Intellij Idea features and I just want to know if this almighty "structureal search and replace" is good for something.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug or a missing feature depending on how you look at it. 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141143

However, it is possible to do it in two steps. First search for the constructor parameters you want to annotate:

```
class $Class$ implements OurCommonInterface {
  $Class$($Type$ $parameter$);
}
```

where `$parameter$` min: `1` max: `unlimited`, `This variable is target of the search` checked.

Then replace the parameter with an annotated parameter in scope `Previous Search Results`:

```
$Type$ $parameter$
```

Replacement template:

```
@JsonProperty("$parameter$") $Type$ $parameter$
```